# Horizontal flipping of images in Python

Tags: cntk

The BrainScript image reader supports horizontal flipping of training images. Is this also supported in Python? I did not see anything about it. Thx!
https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/BrainScript-Image-reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CropType::RandomSize` or `RandomArea` will set `hFlip` to true.

```
m_hFlip = (m_cropType == CropType::RandomSide || m_cropType == CropType::RandomArea);
```